# form submission error in php and html

Tags: php, html, forms, image

```
 if(isset($_POST['btn_upload']))
 {
     $filetmp = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
     $filename = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
     $filetype = $_FILES['photo']['type'];
     $filepath = "photo/".$filename;

     move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);
 }
```

in this code i am getting error as `Undefined index: photo`

here photo is the name of the input file tag which is in different html file

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">Upload Image</label>
<div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
Browse… <input type="file" id="imgInp" name="photo">
</span>
</span>
</div>
<img id='img-upload' />
</div>
```

so i tried this

```
$_FILES['photo']=$_POST['photo'];
```

but then i got error

> Illegal string offset 'tmp_name'
>
> Illegal string offset 'name'
>
> Illegal string offset 'type'

please help me out in this.

thanks in advance

Comment: The form u are using to submit the file, is a form mutiplar?
`<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: yes it is multipart

Comment: Try this, and check if the file is actually getting to the server, in the method u are processing the ur post, do this `echo json_encode($_FILES);`, if it shows nothing it means the file is not reaching the server, let me know to check if i can help u.

Comment: hey thanks but i got the solution actually i had to put multipart in the html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form should include enctype multipart/form-data

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
```

Comment: i have this in the form tag    <form  action="sql.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="contact_form">

Comment: Try to use chrome developer console and check if your data is passing to the script.

Comment: hey thanks it worked i had extra declarations which had to be removed but now im getting this sql syntax error

Comment: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: share your sql query and table structure (by editing your question).

Comment: hey guys thank you so much for ur quick answers successfully stored data into the database i had too remove extra columns which i had previously created but not used.